# Add shape in ActiveCell from different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, button, shapes

I'm trying to add a shape in the ActiveCell in the "Visualizer" worksheet by clicking a button in the "Automater" Worksheet. While Excel is adding the shape in the "Visualizer" worksheet, it's adding it in the "Automater" worksheet ActiveCell's adress.

This is the code:

```
Sub button0_Click()
    Set visualizer = Sheets("Visualizer")
    Set shpOval = visualizer.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, ActiveCell.Left, ActiveCell.Top, 50, 50)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify your ranges.  `visualizer` is not inherited, so you would need to capture in each range, e.g.:

```
visualizer.range(visualizer.cells(1,1),visualizer.cells(2,2))
```

This can be simplified with a `With` statement, allowing changes to be made in one place for the sheet:

```
With visualizer
    .range(.cells(1,1),.cells(2,2))
End with
```

---

Regarding `ActiveCell` and sheet specifying, that doesn't work.  The currently active sheet would need to be assessed for the particular instance/view of Excel's *active* cell.

As such, you need to activate the correct sheet for the specific shape location, you would want to capture your target cell's information, e.g.:

```
with visualizer
    .activate
    dim targetRow as long, targetCol as long
    targetRow = activecell.row
    targetCol = activecell.column
    With .Cells(targetRow,targetCol)    
        Set shpOval = visualizer.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, .Left, .Top, 50, 50)
    End With
end with
```

Please keep in mind, `.Activate` and `.Select` are typically avoided, so wherever you can specify the actual cell value, please do so.  See: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)